# Left introversion operators associated to function spaces on semigroups

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups

I am stuck on the following question for quite sometime now. Please help, any comment is welcome.

Let $S$ be a topological semigroup and $\mathcal{F}$ be a translation invariant, conjugate closed linear subspace of $B(S)$ containing constant functions. For any functional  $\mu\in \mathcal{F}^*$ and $f\in \mathcal{F}$, the left introversion operator is defined as $T_\mu : \mathcal{F} \rightarrow B(S)$ where

$T_\mu f(x) := \mu(L_xf)$ for any $f\in \mathcal{F}$, $x\in S$.

**We need to show** that the set $\{T_\mu f : ||\mu|| \leq 1\}$ is the closure of $cco(\mathcal{O}_r(f))$ in $B(S)$ with respect to the pointwise topology.

Here $cco(E)$ denotes the convex circled hull of $E$ and $\mathcal{O}_r(f)$ denotes the right orbit of $f$, i.e, $\mathcal{O}_r(f) = \{R_xf: x\in S\}$ where $R_xf \in B(S)$ is defined as $R_xf(y) = f(yx) = L_yf(x)$.

Comment: Does S carry the discrete topology? If not, what continuity assumptions are you making about the map S \times S \to S ?

Comment: Do you at least know how to prove this when $\mathcal{F}=B(S)$?

Comment: @Yemon Choi: No, $S$ may not carry the discrete topology. $S$ is any topological semigroup here. So the multiplication map is jointly continuous. I do not see how to approach this problem  for any $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: OK, thanks. Can you at least do the case $S={\bf Z}_+$ and $\mathcal{F}=c_0({\bf Z}_+)$?

Comment: What is $B(S)$?

Comment: @JochenWengenroth I think this is meant to be the bounded functions on $S$, possibly the continuous bounded functions -- I have seen similar notation in some work on abstract harmonic analysis for semigroups

Comment: Carl, I'd like to repeat my suggestion that you try to prove this for $S={\bf Z}_+$ and ${\mathcal F}=c_0({\bf Z}_+)$. If you cannot answer this case, then post it as a separate question here or on MathStackExchange.